# Qt can't find DLL files in external directories

Tags: c++, qt, dll, qt5

I have been working on a QT (ver 5.0.0 mscv2010) project requiring a SiLabs dll:

In the case of DLL in an outside directory:

```
`win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../test_devices/lib/SiLabs/ -lSiUtil`
`INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../test_devices/lib/SiLabs`
`DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../test_devices/lib/SiLabs`
```

However when I put the program under Dependency Walker, it finds that the SiUtil.dll is missing

Now when I change the project file and the SiUtil.dll location to a lib folder in the build folder:

```
`win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/SiLabs/ -lSiUtil`
`INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/lib/SiLabs`
`DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/lib/SiLabs`
```

it works!

This is quite annoying because we are trying to share the library files and avoiding duplications

Thanks

Comment: Dependency walker sounds like you're debugging a runtime issue and the linking step itself works. Qt/Qmake doesn't configure runtime, you have to add the SiLabs directory to the PATH, install it with your binary, etc.

Comment: Thanks Frank, my intent is to deploy the DLLs with the application which will fix the run time issue. What I should have made clear is that the problem occurs when I press that Run button in Qt Creator (i.e. run the application in the build environment). The second project file works where as the first one doesn't.

Comment: Try to set PATH accordingly in the run environment